# Why ajax error is coming in my Data table in .Net?

Tags: javascript, .net, sql-server, model-view-controller, datatable

When I loading table I got ajax error in datatable.(.net)

This is my data table code

```
<table id="productsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>No of Products</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



@section scripts{
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#productsTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Products/GetData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "Code" },
                { "data": "Price" },
                { "data": "Available" }
            ]

        });
    });
</script>
}
```

this is my controller

```
public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
        {
            List<product> proList = db.products.ToList<product>();
            return Json(new { data = proList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

`product` is my db table ,

this is the model

```
public partial class product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Available { get; set; }
    public byte[] is_deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Error Looks like

**DataTables warning: table id=productsTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7**

Comment: Please check the browser > network tab to see what error you are getting on making the ajax all to `/Products/GetData`

Comment: Yes, `/Product/GetData` is a correct URL, I mentioned that wrongly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Click here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S7KWOg

I did not get an error with this:

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index4</title>
    @*added this css*@
    <style>
        body {
            padding-left: 50px;
            width: 80%;
        }
    </style>

    @*removed the bootstrap for better dataTable styling*@

    @*putting all your scripts in the head*@
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @*<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@

    @*added this script*@
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @*need this jquery script*@
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#productsTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    //using home controller instead of products
                    "url": "/Home/GetData",
                    //"url": "/Products/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Code" },
                    { "data": "Price" },
                    { "data": "Available" }
                ]

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="productsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered display">
        @*added display class*@
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>No of Products</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    @section scripts{
        @*moved these scripts to the head*@
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller/Model

```
public class product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Available { get; set; }
    public byte[] is_deleted { get; set; }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        //using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
        //{
        //    List<product> proList = db.products.ToList<product>();
        //    return Json(new { data = proList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //}

        List<product> proList = new List<product>{ new product { Available = 1, Code = "Code1", is_deleted = new byte[1],
                                                                     Name = "Name1", Price = 1.27M, ProductId = 1 },
                                                   new product { Available = 2, Code = "Code2", is_deleted = new byte[2],
                                                                     Name = "Name2", Price = 1.28M, ProductId = 2 },
                                                   new product { Available = 3, Code = "Code3", is_deleted = new byte[3],
                                                                     Name = "Name3", Price = 1.29M, ProductId = 3 } };

        return Json(new { data = proList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult Index4()
    {
        return View();
    }
```